# Merging Functions into one statement on VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, merge

I am making a Student Profile System and I have a form on VB that retrieves data from MySQL to Checkboxes, when there is "1" on the column, the checkbox ticks.

I do this function and queries that was stated below on every single checkboxes. Is there any way to merge this into one query?

```
Sub CheckboxAccess1()
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT access1 FROM tblusers WHERE userid = @userid AND access1 LIKE '1'"
            com = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("userID", TextBox2.Text)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            reader = com.ExecuteReader
            If reader.Read() Then
                CheckBox2.Checked = True
            Else
                CheckBox2.Checked = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
Sub CheckboxAccess2()
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT access2 FROM tblusers WHERE userid = @userid AND access2 LIKE '1'"
            com = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("userID", TextBox2.Text)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            reader = com.ExecuteReader
            If reader.Read() Then
                CheckBox3.Checked = True
            Else
                CheckBox3.Checked = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub CheckboxAccess()
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(str)
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT access1, access2 FROM tblusers WHERE userid = @userid"
            com = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("userID", TextBox2.Text)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            reader = com.ExecuteReader
            reader.Read()
            CheckBox2.Checked = (reader.GetString("access1") = "1")
            CheckBox3.Checked = (reader.GetString("access2") = "1")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I want to clarify on this code (reader.GetString(0) = "1"), is 0 represents the index/column on the database? Sorry I'm new on programming. I really appreciated your answer to my problem!

Comment: @BryanYu, you never need to ask a question here when you can look for yourself. Read the documentation for the `MySqlDataReader.GetString` method and see for yourself. You may be new to programming but you're not new to the internet so you can do a search for yourself and read a page for yourself. By the way, I edited that part, specifically because I DID read the documentation to see if I had that part right and saw that there was a clearer option.